# Is is safe to rename or move class with hibernate @Entity annotation?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

There is a simpel class with `@Entity` annotation. I plan to move it to another package and may rename it. Is it safe operation? (it is assumed that new packages is added to scan). Are there any potential dangerous with mapping moven class to existict table?

Answer (score 1):

It depends.  If you hibernate entities are configured in the java code, then the refactoring will take care of it.  However, if your hibernate configuration is in xml, then you'll have to rename the entry in the xml (as refactoring will not take care of it).

Look for a file called

```
hibernate.cfg.xml
```

If it doesn't exist, then you most likely have a java configuration and will be fine.  If it does exist, find the entity in that file and rename the package in it.